# How to get the count of the rows in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a count of the rows in dataframe:

```
count1 = df[(df['col1'] == xxx) & (df['col2'] == yyy)].count()
```

But it still return Series. How can I get the actual count as int?

Comment: It's not working because you have more than one column, so a series is returned as noted by @EdChum.  You could put ```['col1']``` at the end to get an int.  Or anything else that effectively reduces the series to a single value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `count()` doesn't work as intended, but this does work:

```
df2 = df[(df['col1'] == xxx) & (df['col2'] == yyy)]
count = len(df2) # int
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the resulting Series into a list could help you "tolist()"

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you're expecting here [`df.count()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html#pandas.DataFrame.count) returns a series or df showing you the row or column count, why would you expect a simple scalar value returned?

If you wanted just the row cound then perform `len(count)` or `count.shape[0]`

example:

```
In [173]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,2,2,3,5], 'b':[0,1,1,3,5], 'c':np.random.randn(5)})
df
Out[173]:
   a  b         c
0  0  0 -1.192011
1  2  1  0.290372
2  2  1 -0.092076
3  3  3  0.821918
4  5  5  0.551033
In [180]:

count1 = df[(df['a'] == 2) & (df['b']==1)]
len(count1)
Out[180]:
2
```